# Differential forms and double improper integral

Tags: reference-request, improper-integrals, differential-forms

Can someone suggest me a list of book or workbook with examples and solutions on differential forms and double improper integral?

Answer (score 4):

[Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817637079) by Harold Edwards is a good introductory level explanation of the material with lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Weintraub's [Differential Forms: A Complement to Vector Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0127425101) is an elementary text contains many examples of integrating differential forms and has answers to all exercises. There are many errata in the text however and it would be a good idea to get an updated list from the author's website before reading.

Comment: This book has lots of good basic exercises of the sort I think the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend *[Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130414085)* by Hubbard & Hubbard.  Not only does it cover differential forms, it also integrates the study of linear algebra and multivariable calculus.